# create a matrix from columns of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix like:
`[[1 1 0] [1 0 1] [0 1 0]]`
I want to create another matrix which in each row has a column of the previous matrix and two random numbers in each column.
`[[1,1,0] 0.5 , 0.6  [1,0,1]  0.3 , 0.2  [0,1,0]  0.2 , 0.9]`

Comment: No you don't want that kind of a array.  Make a list if you must, but don't waste time on an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random` library

```
import random as rand

A = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]

result = []

for i in A:
    result.append(i)
    result.append(round(rand.random(), 1))
    result.append(round(rand.random(), 1))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 0], 0.4, 0.6, [1, 0, 1], 0.7, 0.5, [0, 1, 0], 0.9, 0.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in concatenate function and random module to do so.

```
import numpy as np

# original matrix
matrix = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])

# add-on with random numbers (gaussian)
add_matrix = np.random.randn(3,2)

# concatentation
result = np.concatenate((matrix, add_matrix), axis=1)
```

UPDATE: if you want a bit more generalizable code, you can do
`np.random.randn(matrix.shape[0],2)` instead of `np.random.randn(3,2)`.

Comment: Probably better `matrix.shape[0]` than hard-code the `3`.

Comment: In general, I agree, but it is a toy example and probably it is more clear this way.